# how can i make .each() function result by array to join a single array result by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing, each

i just want to compare each value in array. and get high value.
but i have no idea to convert a single array.

here is the code ::

```
wrap.each((index)=> {


        const year = wrap.eq(index).find('.year'),
              list = wrap.eq(index).find('.list'),
              line = wrap.eq(index).children('.line'),
              picker = wrap.eq(index).find('.line span');

            let btnWidth = [list.width()];

            var arr = [];
            arr.push(btnWidth);

            console.log(arr)

      });
```

this result is

[724]

[759]

[687]

[483]

like this but i want make to

[724, 759, 687, 483]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you define `arr` as a new, empty array within each `.each()` iteration.

You can use jQuery's [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method to convert an element collection to an array of values

```js
const wrap = $(".wrap");
const widths = wrap.map((_, elt) => $(elt).find(".list").width()).get();

console.log(widths);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<ul><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:724px">724px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:759px">759px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:687px">687px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:483px">483px</p></li></ul>
```

---

And of course, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const wrap = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
const widths = Array.from(
  wrap,
  (elt) => elt.querySelector(".list")?.offsetWidth
);

console.log(widths);
```

```html
<ul><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:724px">724px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:759px">759px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:687px">687px</p></li><li class="wrap"><p class="list" style="width:483px">483px</p></li></ul>
```

Comment: thanks! that result is what i found.
but i misposted that code before i have alreay defined varriables.

const wrap = $('.HMhistory'); 

so it is done anyway.
therefore would you mind it, can i have a one more question?

the question is compare that array each value, and get the one of the highest value extract and print console.

can you help this?

Comment: @Haem that line of code in my answer is just to facilitate the runnable code.